# Eigenvalues are measurable

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory

Consider an $n\times n$-symmetric matrix A. It is well known that A has n real eigenvalues $\lambda _i$, which we order in an increasing way, i.e. $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq...\leq\lambda_n$. Now the claim is that the mapping $ A\mapsto \lambda=(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ is measurable, but I don't see a way to prove it.

Comment: For certain $A$ you have continuity, by a Gerschgorin circle theorem argument. I think you can extend this argument to get global continuity, but it is tricky because of what happens when the disks intersect.

Comment: Eigenvalues are the reciprocal image of $\{0\}$ by a polynomial...

Comment: @marwalix I'm not sure what the point of that comment was. There are two issues: 1. is the map from a polynomial with real roots to the vector of roots in increasing order "nice"? 2. is the map from a matrix to its characteristic polynomial "nice"? You need both of those to make this work. The answer to the second one is thankfully easy (the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are polynomial functions of the entries of $A$). The answer to the first one is harder: you need the implicit function theorem for the case when the roots are distinct, and something else for when they collide.

Comment: @Ian I completely agree with your two points. I made my comment simultaneously with yours. And I did not comment further after reading you.

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods. Here is one that is simple to describe.

Without loss of generality, all eigenvalues are strictly positive. You can guarantee this by adding $(1+\max_{j} \sum_{i} |a_{ij}| ) I_{n} $ to $A$, a continuous function of the entries.

This is because if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $v$ is a corresponding eigenvector, then $\lambda v_i = \sum_j a_{ij} v_j$. Therefore $|\lambda| \sum_{i} |v_i| \le \sum_{i,j} |a_{i,j}||v_j| \le (\max_{j} \sum_{i}|a_{i,j}|)\sum_{j} |v_j|$, and $\sum|v_j|>0$.

Next, recall that for any $n$ positive  numbers $r_1,r_2,\dots, r_n$,

$$\max_{i} r_i = \lim_{k\to\infty} (\sum_{i\le n} r_i^k)^{1/k}.$$

Therefore you immediately obtain $\lambda_n$ by taking the limit

$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} (\mbox{Tr} (A^k))^{1/k}.$$

This is clearly a measurable function of the entries: it's a point-wise  limit of continuous functions of the entries.

Continue inductively, and define for $1\le j\le n-1$:

$$\lambda_{n-j-1} = \lim_{k\to\infty} (\mbox{Tr} (A^k)-\lambda_{n-j}^k-\lambda_{n-j+1}^k-\dots -\lambda_n^k)^{1/k}.$$

We're done. I hope.

Comment: Very nice idea. Thank you. Side note: You are missing an exponent $k$ in the last line.

Comment: Corrected. Thank you !

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this representation for the maximum of positive numbers, so here's my proof: I just consider the case $n=2$ which can be easily generalised. Wlog set $a<b$. Then $(a^k+b^k)^{1/k}=((a/b)^k+1)^{1/k}*b$. But $1\leq ((a/b)^k+1)^{1/k}=\exp (1/k*\log((a/b)^k+1))\leq \exp (1/k*\log(2))\rightarrow 1$.
Also, beacuse we have the representation $A=O^T\Lambda O$, for an orthogonal matrix $O$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ consisting of the eigenvalues, we have $\text{Tr}(A^k)=\lambda_1+...+\lambda_n$, using that $\text{Tr}(ABC)=\text{Tr}(CAB)=\text{Tr}(BCA)$. Right?

Comment: Above it should be $\text{Tr}(A^k)=\lambda_1^k+...+\lambda_n^k$.

Comment: @Fnacool: Really nice trick, but I still do not understand how, after making your matrix positive and showing that the eigenvalues of this new matrix are measurable, one could go back to the old matrix and show that its eigenvalues are measurable, too. Is the relationship between the eigenvalues of the old and the new matrix expressible in measurable formulas?